# Let us be able to close with the reasoning being that it belongs on GameDev.SE

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration, migration-path-request

It seems that a lot of the times, questions about game development are posted on Arqade and sometimes questions pertaining to gaming are posted on GameDev. With that being said, why can we not close things as being off-topic because they belong on GameDev?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To enable migration paths to other sites for 3kers, we need:

1. a meta question about it, such as this one, and
2. a history of manual migration from mods.

Last time I spoke to Shog9 about this, he looked at the migration stats and found 3 questions we sent there in the last 90 days. He laughed and then politely declined. In this site's lifetime — or, more precisely, in GameDev's lifetime (:P) — we've sent them a total of 33 questions. That's... a question about every 30 days indeed.

We mods can deal with that. :)

Answer (score 4):

Mods can migrate questions to GameDev as needed. Flag a question if you feel this is appropriate.

If every question I saw comments about "belonging on gamedev" got migrated, I think they'd like us a lot less over there.

Comment: But on SO you could close as belonging on SU or SF...

Comment: We try not to migrate crap.  Our latest candidate fulfills that definition admirably.  If we just set up a link to do so, it'd just get closed there, and bounced back here.

Comment: @Jeffreylin and on SO those migration paths are used *much* more often than the one you've proposed here would be.